# jqtree not showing custom attributes

Tags: jquery, jqtree

In the [jqtree docs](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/), it says you can add custom attributes to the data:

> You can also include other data in the objects. You can later access
>   this data. For example, to add an id:
>
> ```
> {
>     label: 'node1',
>     id: 1
> }
> ```

I am sending it JSON that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "label": "foo",
    "id": "12115",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "bar",
        "id": "15273",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "label": "bin",
        "id": "15288",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "label": "baz",
        "id": "33263",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm implementing it like this:

```
$(this).tree({
    dataUrl: 'http://my/server/url/',
    autoOpen: true,
    dragAndDrop: false
});
```

The trees show up fine, but it doesn't pass the 'id' fields through in any way that I can determine.  Am I doing something wrong, or is that functionality no longer supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jqtree does not add an id attribute to the html. It does store the id attribute internally.

You can use the [getNodeById](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#functions-getnodebyid) function to access the internal node.

```
var node = $(this).tree('getNodeById', '15273');
console.log(node.name);
console.log(node.id);
```

If you want to add the id attribute to the html, you could use the **onCreateLi** option. Also see [this example](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/examples/09_custom_html.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's what I figured out and ended up doing, so I'll mark yours as the answer.